# Monitor database requests in Django, tied to line number

Tags: django, django-database

We've got some really strange extraneous DB hits happening in our project. Is there any way to monitor where the requests are coming from, possibly by line number? The SQL printing middleware helps, but we've looked everywhere those kinds of requests might be generated and can't find the source.

If the above isn't possible, any pointers on narrowing down the source would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the code executing queries, you can install [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to figure out what commands are being executed and which tables they're operating on.

Once you've done that, try hooking into the appropriate [Django signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) for those models and using `print` and `assert` to narrow the code.

I'm sure there's a better way to do some of this (a python debugger?) but this is the first thing that comes to mind and probably what I would end up doing myself.

Comment: +1 for the debug toolbar. It should give the full traceback of where each query is being done.

Comment: Yes! django-debug-toolbar is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you want track SQL queries for performance optimization and debug purpose and how to monitor query call in Django
for that this blog will help you out

[Tracking SQL Queries for a Request using Django](https://hub.packtpub.com/tracking-sql-queries-request-using-django/)